# rails_admin keep giving me undefined local variable or method `rails_admin' when access dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-admin

I've followed this:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

And I think I've done everything needed, bundle install, rake db:migrate etc but I can't get rid of:

`undefined local variable or method "rails_admin" for #<#<Class:0x0055e4c3e49c30>:0x0055e4c2e61db8>`

[image]
`
Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried restarting your rails server?

Comment: yes, i've already done that.

Comment: Please add ruby version and rails version to your question as well

Comment: gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5' , ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to fix your route.rb

you can use this configuration :

```
devise_for :admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you follow the [setup instructions](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)

```
rails g rails_admin:install
```

Also can you post the helper method code which is raising the error?

Try changing this in your haml file

```
#change
rails_admin.url 
#to 
rails_admin_url
```

Answer (score 1):

try using href as below. I think it should work if other things are proper.

```
href="#{main_app.url_for(action: action.action_name, controller: 'rails_admin/main', 
model_name: abstract_model.try(:to_param). id: (object.try(:persisted?) && object.try(:id) || nil))}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dashboard to the list of actions on your initializers/rails_admin.rb like this

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    dashboard
  end
end
```

Comment: i've configured that file : https://gist.github.com/ba01ac3b089887c841b92729554dcf30.git